# Byte array replace byte with byte sequence efficiency: iterate and copy versus SelectMany

Tags: c#, arrays, lambda, performance, ienumerable

I'm dealing with a byte array that comprises a text message, but some of the characters in the message are control characters (i.e. less than 0x20) and I want to replace them with sequences of characters that are human readable when decoded into ASCII (for instance `0x0F` would display `[TAB]` instead of actually being a tab character). So as I see it, I have three options:

1. Decode the whole thing into an ASCII string, then use `String.Replace()` to swap out what I want. The problem with this is that the characters seem to just be decoded as the unprintable box character or question marks, thus losing their actual byte values.
2. Iterate through the byte array looking for any of my control characters and performing an array insert operation (make new larger array, copy existing pieces in, write new pieces).
3. Use `Array.ToList<byte>()` to convert the byte array to a `List`, then use `IEnumerable.SelectMany()` to transform the control characters into sequences of readable characters which `SelectMany` will then flatten back out for me.

So the question is, which is the best option in terms of efficiency? I don't really have a good feel for the performance implications of the `IEnumerable` lambda operations. I believe option 1 is out as functionally unworkable, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
// your byte array for the message
byte[] TheMessage = ...;
// a string representation of your message (the character 0x01... 0x32 are NOT altered)
string MessageString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(TheMessage);
// replace whatever you want...
MessageString = MessageString.Replace (" ", "x").Replace ( "\n", " " )...
// the replaced message back as byte array
byte[] TheReplacedMessage= Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(MessageString.ToCharArray());
```

EDIT:

Sample for replacing an 8 Bit byte value

```
 MessageString = MessageString.Replace ( Encoding.ASCII.GetString (new byte[] {0xF7}), " " )...
```

Regarding the performance
I am not 100% sure whether it is the fastest approach... we just tried several approaches though our requirement was to replace "byte array of 1-n bytes" whithin the original byte-array... this came out the fastet+cleanest for our use case (1 MB - 1 GB files).

Comment: This is solution 1 as I described above. I'm still not convinced this will work reliably for unprintable ASCII characters, but assuming it does, is it the most efficient approach? If so, why?

Comment: The ASCII unprintable chararcters 0x01 - 0x20 are not changed by this approach - we use this alot and checked it thouroughly... the documentation states it is clean at least for 7Bits... in our experience we never had a problem with 8 Bit character... I added a sample Replace for 8 Bit Value...